# Border on borderless pie chart, Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm an Illustrator beginner, and I have just made pie chart. I removed the borders but I still end up with a 1 pixel wide border between the pieces of the pie whenever I export to PDF or AI. Please see the attached image (zoomed to make it easier to spot it).

[image]

The question is: How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this for an explanation: [Strange grey bordering/outline in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15419/strange-bordering-in-illustrator/15423#15423)

The white "lines" are due to anti-aliasing. They aren't actually lines, but minute gaps between shapes and for a pixel display the anti-aliasing uses the background color as a base. In your case the yellow.

- You can add a circle behind the chart and fill it with the same color red and the white anti-aliasing will disappear.
- You can group the chart (if it isn't already grouped) then add a new Fill via the Appearance panel. Color the new fill the same red, and move it below the [contents] item in the Appearance Panel.