# Illustrator compound path and clipping mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask, path, illustrator-effects

I'm having an issue with a compound path and a clipping mask. It's driving me absolutely crazy.

There is a very fine outline which I can't seem to get rid of. I've attached screenshots to better-explain what I mean.

Here's the file in illustrator

[image]

I've copied and pasted it into photoshop, and then applied an inner-shadow, which helps demonstrate the issue better. If you look at the "N" the blue strip doesn't look right. It's driving me nuts.

[image]

I hope I've explained myself well enough, but if not - happy to answer any quesitons you may have.

Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange bordering in Illustrator](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15419/strange-bordering-in-illustrator)

Comment: Thanks for responding - tried that, but no joy :(

Comment: Have you tried making the N it's own mask and putting the clipped part in it by itself to see if you get the same result? I know I've run into this before but I can't remember how I fixed it. :/

Answer (score 1):

**1:** Be sure that both blue objects (light and dark) are contained in the same clipping mask. Some people have a habit of using multiple paths for the same shape and it opens up to much room for human error.

**2:** If you want an inner shadow, you can always do that in Illustrator.

**3:** Have you tried placing it in Photoshop as a smart object instead of copy and paste?

Answer (score 0):

Try expanding the appearance of the Compound Path to see if that might help.