# illustrator shape doesnt blend

Tags: adobe-illustrator

am not a newbie in illustrator. but I dnt understand why this is happening.I took pen tool for both sadows. the tutorial am following to creat this tht guy has no boundary between shadows like mine does. i restarted pc- it doesn't go away. I re start illustrator it's still happening. I created even 3 more!! still, it is there... why these two shadows are not blending?? why is that middle line occurring every time?? please help me.[image]

Comment: ermm.. HUH? Please slow down, realize no one here knows what you are trying to accomplish or how things "should" look. Clearly explain the steps you've taken and where a problem occurs.

Comment: you see two shadows there?? i drew it with pen tool. and lower the opacity. but there is a distinctive line between two shadows! i dont want it. usually we draw two shapes. apply same color. it dsnt show the adjacent margin right? but why it is not happening with these  shadows?? why the adjacent margin showing itself?

Comment: are you talking about the white line between the shapes? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27086/a-gap-between-lines-of-joined-path-in-illustrator

Answer (score 0):

Short of opening up your file and seeing what is actually going on here, I can give at least 2 ways as to how that line is showing up:

- There is an extra line that you made with the pen tool that isn't accounted for (on another layer, perhaps even locked, etc.)
- There is a slight overlap between the two shapes causing the line. You can use `View -> Outline` (ctrl-y) to see if this is the case and then snap the vertices of these shapes together to eliminate the overlap.

If none of these things are happening you can always merge the two shapes together using the Pathfinder or Shapebuilder tool.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you.  am gonna try both. i merged it. but it had created more problem. then the shadow covers the whole art. it is a compound object you know i didnt print scrn the whole image. if i had you would have seen there is a cut in the shadow.. oh man. illustrator is not cute sometimes.... nyway thank you