# How to make rough edges smooth in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder

I make some shape in illustrator, then divide all the shape with pathfinder tool. Then i fill all the pieces of shape with different. I found some rough area in the edges, how can I get rid of this problem? [image]

Comment: Hi user3747544, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Where is this screenshot from? From Ai itself, or from a *.pdf viewer?

Comment: have you tried zooming out, lol

Comment: This is due to on-screen anti-aliasing: Possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15419/strange-grey-bordering-outline-in-illustrator Overlapping objects, or placing a colored object *behind* the overall shape would correct this. Again, this is an on-screen only issue due to anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your "rough edges" are actually because there's the smallest amount of negative space between each shape. If you select your shapes and do not have more anchor points than makes sense, this is what's going on.

I would arrange your shapes so that they overlap instead of barely touch, which will knock out your whitespace. For example, in the grey section, your lightest grey to the back, and move your anchor points a bit the the left so that they are past your second shade of grey but are underneath it so you retain the edge to your second shade.

Comment: Hi user56265, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is just space between the shapes. But if moving them closer together doesn't help, make sure that there is no "border" on the shapes and then if you right click the pencil tool you can select **smooth tool** just select the shapes and drag along the lines you wish to smooth.

Good luck and I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!