# anti-aliasing ruining vector illustration with white artifacts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, anti-aliasing

I've created these illustrations using brush and colored it with bucket, added shadows with cutter.

Problem is white artifacts showing between colors and line work. I've read about anti-aliasing, but toggling checkbox would make lines jagged but fix white artifacts or vice versa - in neither state it was pleasing to the eye.

[image]

Comment: I found a post that is similar to your question. One of the answers mentions switching from CMYK to RBG mode to correct on-screen display. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15419/strange-grey-bordering-outline-in-illustrator

Comment: There are a few workarounds for this, but before you try any of them, try using Art Optimized anti-aliasing, when exporting.

Comment: It is called a conflation artefact. It gets asked a lot and has many good answers both on technical abd nontechnical level.

Comment: @DanTabata have seen it, doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @JohnManly I don't have problem with exports, just with vector open in illustrator

Comment: @joojaa I searched with your keyword, could find some similar issues but not directly related.

Comment: @salivan they are not similar issues it is the same issue. There is only one cause for the problem. Erors leading to the problem differ so solutions differ. [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg/65060#65060) is the exact same situation. the solution is different though as you do not have a option to switch this off. But essentially your colors should overlap. Turn the black strokes off and make sure the colors meet under those shapes.

Answer (score 1):

The optimum solution to this problem will be dependent on the final use of the illustrations (i.e. whether they will be used for print or digital). However, one quick fix would be to add a very fine Black key line to all of the black shapes and set that keyline to overprint. The width of the keyline can be very fine so it will not spoil the design. The resulting tiny overlap between the black and coloured areas should be enough to eliminate the white artefacts.

Comment: Final use is lets say digital. What would you recommend? btw, exporting has no trouble, its in illustrator that it looks horrible. Since I want to share this as digital downloadable vector, I'm afraid people will get scared when they open it :)

Comment: That being the case, there is unlikely to be a guaranteed solution because the result that the end user sees will be dependent on their software, preferences, monitor resolution, etc. The above suggestion is still worth a try though as it creates an overlap between the colours which would eliminate the issue in any software that simulates an overprint (and has the option turned on).